# Cannot get directions over alpine pass

Tags: api, google-maps, google-directions-api

We're facing a major issue on our website using Google Maps API.

For many passes in the alps google maps is not able to route over the pass. At first I thought it was due to the pass being closed at that time of the year but it's not.

See sample here: https://www.google.be/maps/dir/46.4143469,9.7151007/46.3481791,9.6032502/@46.4821584,9.4495733,10.75z/data=!4m2!4m1!3e0?hl=en

And we have the same issue using the API, when calling directions API with specific waypoints passing over the pass we can't get any directions.

Anyone else faced this issue?

Comment: Maybe some road segment is marked as closed in Google database. We cannot know this as external users.

Comment: thanks but that doesn't help much......

Comment: If you believe that there is a problem on Google side just send them a report as described in this document: https://support.google.com/maps/answer/3094088